# Is a formal power series a fraction of polynomials?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, examples-counterexamples, formal-power-series

We consider formal power series over a field. Power series such as $x+x^2+ x^3 +\cdots$ can be expressed as fraction of polynomials where the denominator is a unit in the power series ring. There are many other examples that we can construct. Does there exist a power series which cannot written as fraction of polynomials? Are there are some explicit examples?

Comment: You certainly know series as $\sum x^n/n!$ or $\sum x^n/n$. If you want an example which works for all fields, then say $\sum x^{n!}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for a formal power series which is not [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function). In fact almost all formal power series are irrational, closely analogous to how almost all real numbers are irrational. There are many ways to write down counterexamples over different fields; here are a few.

> **Exercise 1:** Over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, any rational power series $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \sum_{a \ge 0} a_n x^n$ has the property that $a_n$ must be eventually periodic.

This is a nice exercise and is the precise analogue of the fact that a rational real number must have an eventually periodic decimal expansion. It follows that any formal power series over $\mathbb{F}_q$ which is not eventually periodic is irrational; an easy example is $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n^2}$.

> **Exercise 2:** If $F$ is a finite or countable field, then there are only countably many rational functions over $F$, but uncountably many formal power series over $F$.

This is not explicit but is one way to formalize the idea that "almost all" formal power series are irrational. For example this result applies to $F = \mathbb{Q}$.

> **Exercise 3:** If $F$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, then any rational power series $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \sum_{a \ge 0} a_n x^n$ has the property that $|a_n|$ grows at most exponentially.

It follows that any formal power series over $\mathbb{C}$ whose coefficients grow faster than exponentially cannot be rational, such as $\sum_{n \ge 0} n! x^n$. Much more precise versions of this claim can also be proven, e.g. $a_n$ must in fact grow exactly like an exponential times a polynomial so also cannot have any other growth rate (so e.g. $a_n$ can't grow like $\sqrt{n}$ or $\exp(\sqrt{n})$), and $a_n$ must in fact have a very specific closed form that most sequences don't have.

> **Exercise 4:** If $F = \mathbb{Q}$, then any rational power series $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \sum_{a \ge 0} a_n x^n$ has the property that at most finitely many primes divide the denominators of each $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

It follows that any formal power series over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the denominators are divisible by infinitely many primes is irrational, such as $\exp(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $\ln (1 + x) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^n}{n}$. Actually these guys are irrational over every field of characteristic $0$ but the proof is a bit trickier.

For the next exercise, say that a power series is **lacunary** if there are arbitrarily large gaps of zero coefficients between its nonzero coefficients; $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n^2}$ is a typical example.

> **Exercise 5:** Every rational power series $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \sum_{a \ge 0} a_n x^n$ has the property that if $\deg g$ consecutive coefficients are zero then it is a polynomial. Hence every lacunary power series is irrational.

This requires no hypotheses on the ground field so, for example, $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n^2}$ is irrational over every field.